# Navigation Drawer move whole screen

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make Navigation Drawer which moves whole screen (whole height, not width). I'm not using ActionBar and other libraries, just default Android drawer. Anyone have any examples?

Comment: Do you mean with or without the ActionBar. There us a difference to how you need to do it.

Comment: Well, I've said I'm not using ActionBar, so, without the ActionBar

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Answer en-route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to set the translationX property of your content view by the pixel amount the drawer has moved to.

In your implementation of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html you should implement `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)`.

In this method you should add this line.
`mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.your_content_id).setTranslationX(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);`

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But is there any way this could work below API 11?

Comment: You could try `mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.your_content_id).offsetLeftAndRight((int)(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset));`

Answer (score 1):

Implements DrawerListener (passing as parameter the R.id of your layout):

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawerLayoutListener implements DrawerListener {

private View _contentDrawer;
private int _idView;

public DrawerLayoutListener(int idView) {
    _idView = idView;
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {}

@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    if (_contentDrawer == null) _contentDrawer = ((View) drawerView.getParent()).findViewById(_idView);
    float moveFactor = (drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_contentDrawer, "translationX", moveFactor).setDuration(0).start();
}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {}

}
```

And set it as listener to your `DrawerLayout`:

```
drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayoutListener(R.id.content_frame));
```

Comment: Thanks, but Simon answered it earlier. Is there any way this could work below API 11?

Comment: Yes! This great [library](http://nineoldandroids.com) has the same api -you only need to change the imports, and it supports since api 1.